# How to verify FCM registration token on server?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I got my Firebase Cloud Messaging registration token for web push.
And I sent this to my server to save in database for later push.
But how can I verify this token is valid or fake?

I have tried [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) but I think this is for Auth tokens not for web push.

Someone else can send request of a random fake token to my server. I want to prevent this before save in db.

Edit: It's solved and I wrote a simple class to use FCM for web push quickly.
https://github.com/emretekince/fcm-web-push

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When sending to an *invalid* registration token, you'll should receive [200 + error:InvalidRegistration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes):

> Check the format of the registration token you pass to the server. Make sure it matches the registration token the client app receives from registering with Firebase Notifications. Do not truncate or add additional characters.

This is the response when you try to send a simple cURL request where the registration token is just randomly made:

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=$[your_server_key_here]" \
       --header Content-Type:"application/json" \
       https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send \
       -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"ABC\"]}"
```

Notice that I added in `"ABC"`, in the `registration_ids` parameter. If ever it is a valid registration token, but is not associated to your project, you'll probably receive [200 + error:NotRegistered](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes).

You can try sending a test message from your server to see the response without sending an actual message towards the device by using the [dry_run](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json) parameter:

> This parameter, when set to true, allows developers to test a request without actually sending a message.

Answer (score 12):

### Using Node Admin SDK

If anyone using firebase **Admin SDK** for **node.js**, there is no need to manually send the request using the `server_key` explicitly. **Admin SDK** provide sending `dry_run` push message to verify the `fcm_token`.

```
function verifyFCMToken (fcmToken) => {
    return admin.messaging().send({
        token: fcmToken
    }, true)
}
```

Use this method like following

```
verifyFCMToken("YOUR_FCM_TOKEN_HERE")
.then(result => {
    // YOUR TOKEN IS VALID
})
.catch(err => {
    // YOUR TOKEN IS INVALID
})
```

### Using Java Admin SDK

You can use following function

```java
public Boolean isValidFCMToken(String fcmToken) {
        Message message = Message.builder().setToken(fcmToken).build();
        try {
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);
            return true;
        } catch (FirebaseMessagingException fme) {
            logger.error("Firebase token verification exception", fme);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: awesome! that is what i was looking for!

Answer (score 7):

According to the docs, you can use `validate_only` for testing the request without actually delivering the message.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages/send

Answer (score 6):

One way is to send a message with the `dry_run` option = true, as is described by AL. in the other answer.

Another way is to use the InstanceId server API:
https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1) for using HTTP v1 of the firebase endpoint URL

After that, you could use this request body with `"validate_only": true` for testing the request without actually delivering the message.

```
{
    "validate_only": true,
    "message": {
        "token": "your fcm token"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With go and adminsdk account credential

```
ctx := context.Background()
opt := option.WithCredentialsJSON([]byte(credential))
app, err := firebase.NewApp(ctx, nil, opt)
if err != nil {
    t.Error(err)
}

msg := &messaging.Message{
    Notification: &messaging.Notification{
        Title: "Hi",
        Body:  fmt.Sprintf("Welcome at %d", time.Now().Unix()),
    },
    Token: pushToken,
}

fcmClient, err := app.Messaging(ctx)
run, err := fcmClient.SendDryRun(ctx, msg)
if err != nil {
    t.Error(err)
}
fmt.Println(run)
```