# The scope of Firebase Instance Id and Token

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've read a lot of articles about `Firebase Instance Id` and `registration token` [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId), [here](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).

I have some confusions about their **scope and relationship** between `Instance Id` and `Token`. I would like to validate that my understandings are correct or wrong.

1. `Instance Id` is generated per **App**. Not per **installed device**. For example, if you have Mail app and Notes App, you will have **two** Instance Id on firebase.
2. `Token` is generated per installed devices. For example, if you have **ten** users installing your app, you will have **ten** registration tokens.
3. One `Instance Id` will have many registration tokens.
4. Normally, we only have to keep `registration tokens` (not Instance Id) on our App Server to send **push notifications**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Partly correct. An InstanceID pertains to the app instance. In your example, if you have the Mail App and the Notes App, each has their own *instance* id, but the two are not the same, so they can't be grouped together.

   Think of the app instance as the app installation. If you have installed the app on the device, it has the app instance. If you uninstall it, it is also removed, if you re-install it, it's a *new app instance*.
2. Correct. But there's also a possibility to have multiple tokens for the same device, but this only pertains to having [multiple senders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37981412/4625829).
3. Possible. See #2.
4. Yes. The registration token is the value needed as a target for push notifications.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. About Instance ID, if my Notes app is installed on ten different devices, will there be ten different Instance Id or only one Instance Id?

Comment: Ten different IDs. When you install your app, you could actually call `FirebaseinstanceId.getId()` which would return the value for that specific *app instance*. And when you call `getToken()` (currently) it returns the token as `<instance_id>:<token>` -- but the registration token is recognized as this exact whole value.

Comment: I've accepted your answer. According to the statement "If you uninstall it, it is also removed". How can our App server knows this Instance Id or Registration token has been deleted (or invalidated) on device?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41552610/4625829) (Diego's answer is also good)

Comment: You are really awesome.

Comment: Thank you. Good luck with your app. :)