# How can I check if string is a valid FCM token?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

How can I check if a string is a valid FCM token.
In my experience the FCM token changes over the time.
In my project, I need to check if a token is a valid one in the server side using Node.js.

How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to verify FCM registration token on server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41552610/how-to-verify-fcm-registration-token-on-server)

Answer (score 1):

You can make you use of the Instance ID Service to find out whether the token is valid or not.
Refer to this link: https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server