# Validate Firebase Registration Tokens

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there a way to validate Firebase registration tokens on my server without making a round trip to Firebase servers? I just want to know if they are valid, not necessarily active.

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: As crazy as it may sound, it's part of the authentication strategy.

Comment: Anonymous authentication to be more precise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Cloud Messaging - How to validate Tokens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38442434/firebase-cloud-messaging-how-to-validate-tokens)

Comment: @FranciscoMateo - not a duplicate as I want to validate it without making network calls to Firebase servers

Comment: Retracted vote to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to validate tokens on your own.

I presume that you intend to validate it by checking the format, which would be unadvisable. [Token formats have the tendency to change as Google wants it too.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39964597/4625829)