# How to check if user disabled notifications in FCM?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging in my Dart/Flutter app. The code below updates a user doc with a retrieved android notification token.

```
FirebaseMessaging().getToken().then((token) {
  _usersRef.doc(user.id).update({
    "notificationAndroidToken": token,
  });
});
```

I then read the `notificationAndroidToken` in my cloud functions. Works great except I had wrongly assumed the token would be invalid if the user had shut off their notifications (e.g., empty or null). What's the best way for determining if notifications are enabled for my app in cloud functions? I'm finding some hits in my searches but many are outdate or for a different dev environment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase Cloud Messaging - How to validate Tokens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38442434/firebase-cloud-messaging-how-to-validate-tokens)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The firebase_messaging package does not provide any method for checking if notifications are enabled by calling [NotificationManagerCompat.areNotificationsEnabled](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationManagerCompat#areNotificationsEnabled()) on the platform. The [awesome_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications) package provides such a [isNotificationAllowed](https://pub.dev/documentation/awesome_notifications/latest/awesome_notifications/AwesomeNotifications/isNotificationAllowed.html) method.

Comment: Perfect. I was planning to check out awesome_notifications anyway because of its gorgeous notifications. Will give it a try

Comment: @buttonsrtoys does it work?